# PHP - DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string

Tags: php, date, datetime

I am pulling DateTime timestamp result from another table which is set as:

When dumping specific value of `$post->getUploadTime()` I get:

```
"2602585961"
```

It's in string format.

In my entity I have modified the setter to:

```
public function setStartTime($startTime)
{
    $date = new \DateTime($startTime);
    $this->startTime = $date->getTimestamp();
    return $this;
}
```

And my code:

```
$newEntityObject->setStartTime(intval($post->getUploadTime()));
```

I am using `intval()` to transform string to integer *(timestamp)* so I can insert it in db but I get an error:

> DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2602585961) at position 8 (6): Unexpected character"

It's an error with or without the `intval()`.
I can not figure out what is wrong?

I know there are a lot of posts about the issue. I tried them, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Where does that timestamp come from? Currently, the timestamp starts with 16, and the one you gave is 31 years from the future

Comment: Also, how is this related to Symfony? Please either explain the relation, or remove the irrelevant tags

Comment: Why do you have`\ ` before DataTime ? And I think DateTime consructor ask for `now` or the format date, not an int.
Source: https://www.php.net/manual/fr/datetime.construct.php

Comment: DateTime except an actual date for example '2021-06-30' not unix timestamp.
You could instantiate the DateTime class then use ->setTimestamp function on it.

Comment: @Elikill58 - I expect the `\DateTime` is because the posted source code is declared inside a namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Try :

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($startTime);
$this->startTime = $date->getTimestamp();
```

But since you are trying to assign a timestamp to your startTime property and you are already passing a timestamp to your function you can just assign whatever timestamp you are passing:

```
$this->startTime = $startTime;
```

Comment: Thank you but the given answer gives "DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given @kopz

Comment: The code in the answer does not pass any parameter to DateTime ...

Answer (score 1):

You have a timestamp, and you are trying to make it a `DateTime` and get timestamp from the new datetime object.

The DateTime constructor only accept specific [date and time format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

Also, the given value refer to the year 2052. So it's possible that you have another issue before.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert to a number. Because you need a string argument that starts with @
You need use @. Read Documentation.

```
 <?php
    
    $a = "@2602585961";
    
    function setStartTime($startTime)
    {
        $date = new \DateTime($startTime);
        $b = $date->getTimestamp();
        return $b;
    }
    
    echo setStartTime($a);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.formats.compound.php

In your code:

```
$newEntityObject->setStartTime("@" .  $post->getUploadTime());
```

Comment: Thank you but the given answer gives "DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given @АлександрЧерножуков

Comment: @pohofo You must pass a string like "@2602585961" in your method 
setStartTime

Comment: @pohofo for test do it $newEntityObject->setStartTime("@2602585961");